# Connect three tables with foreign key and many to one

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have three tables

1. common_addons.
2. hotel_addons.
3. menu

id of `common_addons` is foreign_key of attribute `common_addons_id` in  `hotel_addons` and id of `hotel_addons` is foreign_key of attribute `hotel_addons_id` in table `menu`.

```
        $this->db->join('hotel_addons', 'hotel_addons.id = menu.addon_id');
        $this->db->join('common_addons', 'addons.id = hotel_addons.addons_id');
        $this->db->from('menu');
        $this->db->join('menu', 'menu.addon_id = hotel_addons.id');
```

I want `common_addons`'s `name` through table `menu`, which contains attribute `hotel_addons_id`. attribute `hotel_addons_id` contains multiple `ids` of hotel_addons seprated by commas(through Implode function).

Comment: `contains multiple ids of hotel_addons seprated by commas` not a great idea.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix so what would you sugest it's one 2 many field?

Comment: I would suggest using a bridge table, another table that joins both `menu` and `hotel_addons` because that seems to be a `Many to Many` relationship.  You can only represent a `Many to One` with a single table, so add a 3rd table that is a ManyToOne to both the other tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have now

```
menu
--------------
id                           1
hotel_addons_id              1,2,3,4
```

This is not an "Answer" so much as it is explaining how a ManyToOne, and a OneToMany, can make a ManyToMany

```
hotel_addons
--------------
id                           1        //one to many - one addon has many records in the bridge table

menu_hotel_addons  (bridge table)  = many to many
-------------------------
menu_id                        1     //many to one  - many bridge records point to the menu
hotel_addons_id                1     //many to one  - many bridge records point to the addons table

 menu
 --------------
id                           1     //one to many  - one menu has many records in the bridge table
```

In the bridge table the Primary key is a compound key of both foreign keys, each foreign key, is a surrogate key ( auto increment ).

In other words a   Menu can have many addons, and addons can belong to many menu items.   The way you have it now, is a poor hack that will never give you what you need.

You cannot join on a comma separated list ( not easily at least ).  Its much easier to do something like this:

```
     SELECT 
        m.*,
        a.*
     FROM
         menu AS m
     JOIN
          menu_hotel_addons AS ma
     ON 
        m.id = ma.menu_id
     JOIN
        hotel_addons  AS a
     ON
        ma.hotel_addons_id = a.id
```

Etc...

Comment: thanks got it now, have to make a bridge table, right

Comment: yes, that is how you would typically define a ManyToMany relationship, it can be done with a CSV list, but you would need to put the commas at the beginning and end, and use like `,1,4,`  and `,13,4,` That way you could do `ON hotel_addons_id LIKE '%,1,%'`  without the beginning and end, `Like '%1%'` would wrongly match both `13` and `1`, if that makes sense.  But it's still a mess, I would avoid if possible, and performance would be crap.

Comment: you would need to use something like this  `ON hotel_addons_id LIKE CONCAT('%,', menu_id, ',%')` and other crap, so it would just be a mess.  I am not sure you could even do that in the ON clause. If that makes sense.

Comment: It's best to "follow" the rules in this case, I have used the list ( like above ) but only for Materialized path Tree data, which is a whole other subject.